# Как посчитать пустые строки в таблице с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript

Нужно посчитать пустые строки в таблице между текстовыми строками.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нужно выбрать все строки, выбрать из полученной коллекции пустые строки, получить длину выбранной коллекции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var table = document.querySelector('table'),
    tdIndex = 1;

var n = 0; // Счётчик пустых

// Делаем цикл по всем tr в таблице
for(var i = 0, tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr'); i < tr.length; i++){
  // Проверяем, пустой ли td
  if(tr[i].querySelectorAll('td')[tdIndex].innerHTML == ''){
    n++; // Прибалвяем 1 к счётчику
  };
};

console.log(n); // Выводим количество пустых
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Строка</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Строка</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Строка</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Строка</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Строка</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Строка</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Строка</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Строка</td><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: делать в условии цикла поиск по селектору (`tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr')`) не лучшая идея с т.з. производительности. также лучше использовать встроенные селекторы `table.rows` вместо `table.querySelectorAll('tr')`, `table.cells[tdIndex]` вместо `table.querySelectorAll('td')[tdIndex]`

Answer (score 4):

```js
// Проверяется ячейка с индексом 1
console.info(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table tr')).filter(tr => tr.cells[1].innerHTML.trim() === '').length);
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Строка</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Строка</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Строка</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Строка</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Строка</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Строка</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Строка</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Строка</td><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Красивый ответ, и гораздо лучше первого) Хорошее решение!

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, я покраснел как моя ава :) Благодарю.

Comment: @Other Очень круто. bravo за такой ответ

Comment: @L.Vadim, https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/15/3e/b9/153eb94aa5f841a37639a9ebf94ccfa7.jpg

Comment: Жалко, что Explorer не подерживает Array.from

Comment: @L.Vadim, 1) Кому от сдался? 2) Специально для осла есть паки полифиллов.

Answer (score -1):

Смотря насколько пустые. Если предполагается, что у них вообще ничего в разметке нет (в том число пробелов), то можно так:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(2):empty").length)
```

```css
table, tr, td { border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid; }
td:empty { background: silver; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>Строка</td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Строка</td><td>0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Строка</td><td>0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Строка</td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Строка</td><td>0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Строка</td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Строка</td><td>0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Строка</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Выглядит довольно опасно, любой пробел или перенос поломает подсчёт. Но это всё же круто :)

Comment: @Other, да, поломает. Об этом написано в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо, кэп. Ещё плохо что масштабируемость плохая.

Comment: @Other, масштабируемость?

Comment: Ну да, вдруг надо изменить правила и считать пустыми и те, где будет `0`?